# How to solve "SLF4J: Failed to load class" error without using slf4j implementation?

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j, amazon-kinesis

I have a client that use log4j with the following POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>kinesis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I call: new DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain() (Which was provided by Kinesis dependency) I get the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

One possible solution is to force lo4j2 to use slf4j implementations i.e.

```
<!-- I DONT WANT TO USE log4j-slf4j-impl             -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**But** I don't want to use slf4j I want to use the native log4j implementation. So how can I get rid of those error logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the maven goal dependency:tree to print the dependency tree for your project. I ran this against a pom which only had the amazon kinesis dependency and the result was this:

```
\- software.amazon.awssdk:kinesis:jar:2.16.51:compile
...
[INFO]    +- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:jar:2.16.51:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
...
```

Which means the only thing you can do short of rewriting sdk-core to remove the dependency is to add the [binding](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/) to send all slf4j logging to log4j2.